# Close modal by using back button with hash route

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a modal in vuejs that I am opening/closing by passing the prop `isActive` and I want to close the modal when the user clicks on the back button.

When the modal is open I add the hash `#modal` to the url and when the modal closes I remove the hash.

I am trying to get the modal to close when the user clicks on the back button but currently it does not, it just removes the hash.

The modal will close if I click on the `close()` method so it looks like the `eventListener()` isn't working correctly.

How can I close the modal when the user clicks on the back button?

**modal.js**

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    
export default {
  props: {
    isActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
   computed: {
     hashChange() {
       console.log(this.isActive)
       if(this.isActive) {
         window.location.assign('#modal')
        } else {
          history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
        }
      },
    },
    methods: {
      close() {
        this.$emit('close');
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.close());
    },
    destroyed() {
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.close());
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

HashChange is based on isActive value and isActive value is based on hashChange so it's circular and of course this way wont work instead you can directly listen to the back button as follows and remove hashChange completely it's useless in this scenario:

```
 methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit('close');
    },
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.close, false);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.removeEventListener("backbutton", this.close);
  }
```

In the router add:

```
// This listener will execute before router.beforeEach only if registered
// before vue-router is registered with Vue.use(VueRouter)

window.popStateDetected = false
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
  window.popStateDetected = true
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const IsItABackButton = window.popStateDetected
  window.popStateDetected = false
  if (IsItABackButton && from.name === //The name of the route you are using) {
    next(false) 
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: thanks but if I click on the back button it still seems to go back rather than closing the modal

Comment: You can handle this with vue router ill edit my answer to show you an example

Comment: @tomharrison or you can try to history.replaceState({} inside close